# AnimatePresence framer motion exit doesn't work in react element

Tags: arrays, reactjs, animation, react-context, framer-motion

Im new to react and I'm doing a little shopping cart functionality like removing item and adding item to the cart, I used framer motion to give some animation when item is added or removed. The animation works when item is added, it doesn't animate when its removed, The scenario here is I tried to use **react context API** to store the items, i have put **AnimatePresence**  tag to surround my element and add **exit** property but still i don't get any animation when the item is removed

```
const SideCartItem = ({ product }) => {
  const [{ basket }, dispatch] = useStateValue();

  const removeFromBasket = () => {
    // Remove item from the basket
    dispatch({
      type: 'REMOVE_FROM_BASKET',
      id: product.id,
    });
  };

  return (
    <AnimatePresence>
      <ItemWrapper
        as={motion.div}
        initial={{ x: -70 }}
        animate={{ color: '#481fff', x: 0 }}
        exit={{ x: -70 }}
      >
        <MainInfo>
          <img src={product.image} alt={product.title} />
          <p>
            price: <strong>{formatCurrency(product.price)}</strong>{' '}
          </p>
        </MainInfo>
        <TotalSection>Total: -</TotalSection>
        <RemoveSection onClick={removeFromBasket}>
          <p>Remove Item</p>
          <span>
            <strong>x</strong>
          </span>
        </RemoveSection>
      </ItemWrapper>
    </AnimatePresence>
  );
```

I break the component like so:
on parent element i do:

```
          {basket.map((product) => (
            <SideCartItem
              key={product.id}
              product={product}
              basket={basket}
            ></SideCartItem>
          ))}
```

And the code at the top is the child component namely SideCartItem.js

for additional info is I used **styled components** in my project. There might be something to do with it. Does anybody have any idea to solve this problem? thankyou

This is piece of code from reducer.js

```
    case 'REMOVE_FROM_BASKET': {
      const index = state.basket.findIndex((item) => item.id === action.id);

      let newBasket = [...state.basket];
      newBasket.splice(index, 1);

      return {
        ...state,
        basket: newBasket,
        isExist: false,
      };
    }
```

Comment: Show us a `removeFromBasket` method please

Comment: I've included method and also the reduce.js above @UladzKha check it out